# Laravel throttle reset when refresh

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-7

i've tried following these tutorial  https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-too-many-login-attempts-restrict-and-customize/

here is my login controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $maxAttempts = 3; // Default is 5
    protected $decayMinutes = 1; // Default is 1
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function authenticated()
    {
        Alert::success('Informasi Pesan', 'Selamat datang ' . auth()->user()->name);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'nrp';
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        Alert::success('Informasi Pesan', 'Logout Berhasil');
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

it's work but when i refresh the page, time limit will reset and i can login, how's to fix this?

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't help us much. Edit question with more details (logs, error logs, code used where 'not working' etc). Help us to help you.

Comment: i have edit my question